# Is it possible to specify an Android debug key in Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, android-keystore

I can run the Android project on the device in release mode, but I wonder if it is possible to specify a debug keystore so I don't need to run the app in release mode. I am using the [Google Maps plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) and I need the app to be signed with a particular key for the map to display.